# Detecting if a process is still running

Tags: c++, windows, process

I need to check if a process with a given HANDLE is still running, I tried to do it using the following code however it always returns at the second return false, even if the process is running.

```
bool isProcessRunning(HANDLE process)
{
    if(process == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)return false;

    DWORD exitCode;
    if(GetExitCodeProcess(process, &exitCode) != 0)
        return false;//always returns here

    return GetLastError() == STILL_ACTIVE;//still running
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can test the process life by using

```
bool isProcessRunning(HANDLE process)
{
   return WaitForSingleObject( process, 0 ) == WAIT_TIMEOUT;
}
```

Comment: Just needed to add a check for the INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE since that reported the process was running when it wasn't even valid :)

Comment: APIs like WaitForSingleObject should never return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE if you have a process handle open, even if it is terminated. The handle and underlying object must stay open until explicitly closed by the referencing processes (or those processes are terminated). Are you sure you're not trying to call it on the process ID and not a handle?

Comment: I meant a check before the WaitForSingleObject, in the event the process hadn't yet been created, so the handle was still at the value I initialised it to, ie INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, since passing INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE to WaitForSingleObject always times out (ie INVALID_HANDLE_VALUEis never in a signaled state it seems).

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683189%28VS.85%29.aspx

> **Return Value**
>
> If the function succeeds, the return
>   value is nonzero.
>
> If the function
>   fails, the return value is zero. To
>   get extended error information, call 
>   *GetLastError*.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a bit late, but your code should read like this if you want the results you expect.

```
bool isProcessRunning(HANDLE process)
{    
    DWORD exitCodeOut;

    // GetExitCodeProcess returns zero on failure
    if( GetExitCodeProcess( process, &exitCodeOut ) == 0 )
    {
        // Optionally get the error
        // DWORD error = GetLastError();
        return false;
    }
    // Return if the process is still active
    return exitCodeOut == STILL_ACTIVE;
}
```

If you only have the process ID (PID), this snippet will work (sans error checking):

```
bool isProcessRunning(DWORD processID)
{    
    if( HANDLE process = OpenProcess( PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION, FALSE, processID ) )
    {
        DWORD exitCodeOut;
        // GetExitCodeProcess returns zero on failure
        if( GetExitCodeProcess( process, &exitCodeOut ) != 0 )
        {
            // Return if the process is still active
            return exitCodeOut == STILL_ACTIVE;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This approach should be avoided, because it is possible to get STILL_ACTIVE for a process that has exited.  (It is a valid exit code.)

Comment: @HarryJohnston If and only if the process uses 259 as an exit code, correct? Microsoft advises on not using this as an error code. As the process I am checking has no chance to return 259 (as I wrote it), it's a perfectly acceptable use of the exit code. This seems like a bogeyman that only applies when you're checking the exit code of a process you have no power over. (It is good to know and be aware of, however)

Comment: In that particular scenario, this approach *might* be acceptable.  The OP didn't say whether or not the process they were checking was their own code, though, and your answer didn't state that as a requirement either.

Comment: ... personally, given how easy it is to use WaitForSingleObject, I just don't see any advantage in using GetExitCodeProcess instead.  When you can eliminate the risk the easy way, by using WaitForSingleObject, or the hard way, by checking every possible exit path for the child program, including any third-party libraries you may be using, well, why do it the hard way? :-)

Comment: Just tried using `WaitForSingleObject`, and it returns WAIT_TIMEOUT even if the process is still kicking, likely because we are using `QSharedMemory`, which locks the process from receiving events (it's already waiting, basically). As such, using `WaitForSingleObject(p, 0)` is not possible in our specific use case. There's the advantage :-) I may have come across this when I implemented the feature originally, but forgot the specifics of why I chose `GetExitCodeProcess`.  All that said, it was a helpful exercise, and hopefully it helps someone in the future.

Comment: It's *supposed* to return `WAIT_TIMEOUT` if the process is still kicking!  If the process has exited, it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`.  Note that whether or not the process is "receiving events" is irrelevant; neither GetExitCodeProcess nor WaitForSingleObject care what the process is doing, if anything, only whether or not it has exited.  (By all means, leave this answer in place; it demonstrates what the OP was doing wrong, after all.  I'm just pointing out, for future readers, that this isn't the best way of checking whether the process has exited.)

Comment: You're right, I read the answer above incorrectly. I'm using OpenProcess, are you aware of any pratfalls when using SYNCHRONIZE access right versus PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION?

Comment: Typically that isn't a problem, because you can use the handle you got when creating the process, which has full access to the child.  If the process you're monitoring isn't a child ... well, it would be very unusual to have `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION` permission but not `SYNCHRONIZE` permission, but it is possible if the ACL for the process has been explicitly modified.  That's a legitimate example of an edge case where you might need to use GetExitCodeProcess.  (I doubt it applies in your situation though.)

Comment: Note that if you are using the handle for more than one thing, you can request more than one access right in the call to OpenProcess, e.g., `PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | SYNCHRONIZE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `EnumProcesses()` to get all processes running on Windows.
Something like:

```
bool IsProcessRunning(int pid)  
{  
unsigned long processes[2048];  
unsigned long num_proc = 0;  
unsigned long needed = 0;  

  // assume that 2048 processes are enought  
  if (EnumProcesses(processes, sizeof(processes), &needed))  
   num_proc = needed / sizeof(DWORD);  

  for (int i = 0; i < num_proc; i++)  
    if (processes[i] == pid)  
      return true;  

   return false;  
}
```

Comment: @gimpf It's still potentially useful, regardless of how complicated it is.

Comment: Very inefficient though, and since it uses a process ID rather than a handle, subject to an inherent race condition.  *Potentially* useful, I guess, but probably only in edge cases.